# cassandra data model step by step

Tags: cassandra

I've started to learn cassandra, at first I want to learn cassandra data model but I don't know from where I must start, I have seen many web pages and the cassandra documentation (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_intro_c.html)
but I really confused. In its documentation it only talks about some examples that is so similiar to relational db without talking about super column concept or others concepts which we can find these concepts in others urls.
I need a step by step tutorial for data modeling which is straight forward.

Regards

Comment: doesn't exist any documentation,

Comment: You don't want to read anything about super columns or column families. Anything you see with those terms should be ignored. Those concepts are quickly becoming obsoleted

Comment: so, what documentation should we read?

Answer (score 0):

Although CQL looks similar to SQL, they are very different.  CQL is very limited compared to SQL and you need to understand how data is stored and retrieved in Cassandra based on the partition key and clustering columns.  Until you understand how the keys work, you will be lost.

I haven't seen a very good overview of Cassandra on the web, but if you're willing to spring for a book, a good introduction to Cassandra and how it works is called "Apache Cassandra Hands-On Training Level One".